# Why isn't my DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping being called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have been following the instructions [here](http://karthikg.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/athandlerinterceptor-for-spring-mvc/) to implement a spring mvc handler interceptor using annotations and overriding DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.

However, my Interceptor is never called.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

I have implemented @Interceptors as in the blog post.

I've created one Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class InterceptorSpike extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public InterceptorSpike() {
        System.err.println("InterceptorSpike initialised");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        throw new RuntimeException("Yay, intercepted!");
    }
}
```

And a test controller:

```
@Controller
@Interceptors({InterceptorSpike.class})
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void doSomething() {
        System.err.println("I'm doing something, have I been intercepted??");
    }
}
```

A sample of my handler (mostly the same as the blog post)

```
@Component
public class HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping extends DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping {

    public HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping() {
        System.err.println("HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping initialised");
    }
...
```

*[EDIT - Ignore, left for completeness. I have reverted these steps to use autowiring again]
I originally autowired this using @Component, but moved it into the app context as I've been attempting different fixes.

I added the order, and I'm not using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.  These were suggested by some posts whilst I was looking for solutions. 
[/EDIT]*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
       default-autowire="byName">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>
<context:spring-configured/>

<!-- removed manual wiring -->

</beans>
```

And finally, here's my test :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/test-app-context.xml"})
public class ControllerInterceptorTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private TestController controller;

    @Test
    public void shouldInterceptMethod() {
        Map<String, DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping> mappings = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.class);
        for (String key : mappings.keySet()) {
            DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping mapping = mappings.get(key);
            System.out.println(String.format("key [%s], order [%s], value = %s", key, mapping.getOrder(), mapping.getClass().getCanonicalName()));
        }
        controller.doSomething();
        fail("should have thrown exception");
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping initialised
InterceptorSpike initialised
key [handlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping], order [2147483647], value = com.xxx.interceptors.HandlerInterceptorAnnotationAwareHandlerMapping
I'm doing something, have I been intercepted??
java.lang.AssertionError: should have thrown exception
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
...
```

getHandlerExecutionChain on my new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping is never called.

Thank you for reading this far - I know there is a lot here!

Can anyone see what I've missed or done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue might be in this line:

```
private TestController controller = new TestController();
```

You need to get the "controller handle" from the context and not initialize yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I can see that would have been an issue.  Unfortunately, after updating my code as above, I still have no interception...

Comment: The more I think on this, the more i feel that this should work in a servlet environment where you get actual request to controller. Did you try deploying your code and see if the interceptor is getting triggered or not ?